# Links not working Django

Tags: django

In my base.html the links on the nav bar are not working for some reason. I've wrote it correctly, but when I hover over the link it doesn't do anything.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="900"><a href="{% url 'register' %}"><strong>Join Us?</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="active" role="presentation" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="900"><a href="{% url 'login'%}"><strong>Log In</strong></a></li>
```

**Urls.py**

```
url('^delta/$', aircraft_delta, name='aircraft_delta'),

#aircraft/detail/1
url('^aircraft/detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', aircraft_detail, name='aircraft_detail'),

#aircraft/
url(r'^aircraft/$', list_aircraft, name='aircraft_home'),

#login/
url(r'^login/', login_view, name="login"),

#logout/
url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),

#register/
url(r'^register/', register_view, name="register"),

#upload/aircraft
url(r'^upload/aircraft/$', aircraft_create),
```

**Root urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('aircraft.urls')),]
```

Comment: Show your root and your app's `urls.py` files, please

Comment: @nik_m there you go

Comment: @nik_m nope no error. It just doesnt do anything. But when I type manually it works

Comment: If you right-click on the link and inspect it what is the value of `href` being rendered?

Comment: @nik_m <a href="/login/"><strong>Log In</strong></a> Its recognising it. But not doing anything

Comment: Are you closing the ul tag?

Comment: Yeah css and html is all fine

Comment: I've got it working. Apparently within my link div "class=active" was stopping it. Removing it made it work. Thanks guys

Comment: So you click on it and it doesn't do anything. Hmmm... I think a javascript script prevents it from being clicked. Try to render a plain HTML file with only those 2 links, without any js.

Comment: @nik_m I got it working. Read previous comment :)

Comment: Yes. We just wrote it simultaneously! Glad it worked.